# Reformatting JSON string from Facebook's Graph API with JS

Tags: javascript, json, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove a wrapper from a JSON Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222008/how-do-i-remove-a-wrapper-from-a-json-object)

When using the graph api, the array I'm using for friends...

`(https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=...)`

...looks like this ->

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "Person 1",
         "id": "123123121"
      },
      {
         "name": "Person 2",
         "id": "123123122"
      },
      {
         "name": "Person 2",
         "id": "123123123"
      },
   ]
}
```

Is there any easy way to reformat the array (with javascript) like this? ->

```
[
  {
     "name": "Person 1",
     "id": "123123121"
  },
  {
     "name": "Person 2",
     "id": "123123122"
  },
  {
     "name": "Person 2",
     "id": "123123123"
  },
]
```

EDIT: Apologies I should have mentioned - if this could be possible with javascript please let me know, I can reformat the json strings with php but load times are too slow.

Cheers

Comment: server-side, client-side, language, etc. ?

Comment: Am I missing the point here or do you just want to remove to outer object wrapper?

Comment: Yeah, just the "data" wrapper! Apologies if this is basic, I'm new to JSON!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I've understood the requirement correctly here, but it seems like you just want an array of objects.  That is what `data` contains.

So what you are getting is:

```
{    // outer object wrapper
   "data": [  // array of data objects
      {  // first data object
         "name": "Person 1",
         "id": "123123121"
      },
```

If what you want is an array of objects then just take the `data` array.  It is wrapped in an outer object like this because sometimes Facebook has to pass other information alongside the data, like paging info, in which case your response would look like:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "Person 1",
            "id": "123123121"
        } // etc
    ],
    "paging": {
        {
            // paging information
        }
    ]
}
```

If you need more info, please update you question with the `FB.api` call you are making.